# how to bind xml to gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, bind

This is my xml file

```
<ISPChecklist>
            <Domain name="Coping Skills">
            <Indicator>
                Client shows impovement in either 1 of the areas listed below and shows reduction in frequency of inapporiate coping behaviors :
                - anger management
                - ability to make concrete plans about his/her future
                - self percetion/self worth
                - expand internal locus of control.
            </Indicator>
            <AttainmentDate></AttainmentDate>
            <Remarks></Remarks>
        </Domain>
</ISPChecklist>
```

This is my grid view

```
<asp:GridView ID="ISPChecklist" runat="server" 
                OnRowDataBound="OnDataBound" 
                onselectedindexchanged="ISPChecklist_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Domain" DataField= "Domain" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Indicator" DataField="Indicator" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date Of Attainment">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TB_Date" Columns="5"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Remarks">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TB_Remarks" Columns="5"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

This is my .cs file

```
DataSet checklistDataSet;

string filePath = Server.MapPath("clientISPChecklist.xml");
        checklistDataSet = new DataSet();
        //Read the contents of the XML file into the DataSet

        checklistDataSet.ReadXml(filePath);
        ISPChecklist.DataSource = checklistDataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        ISPChecklist.DataBind();//errors occurs here
```

Whenever i run this set of codes, i would receive an error message that states that "A field or property with the name 'Coping Skills' was not found on the selected data source". Does anyoen knows how to solve it? if not are there any tutorials or guides available

Answer (score 1):

Use [XMLDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.xmldatasource.xpath.aspx) and `XPath()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the Linq-XML is better option.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(MapPath("~/filename.xml"));

var result = from n in doc.Descendants("Domain")
             select new
                {
                   Domain = n.HasAttributes ? n.Attribute("name").Value : "",
                   Indicator=n.Element("Indicator").Value,
                   AttainmentDate = n.Element("AttainmentDate").Value,
                   Remark=n.Element("AttainmentDate").Value 
               };

ISPChecklist.DataSource = result.ToList();
ISPChecklist.DataBind();
```